# React Form Field on change function not passing target value to setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This code could use some improvement, but for now, is there a reason why the name property inside `setState` cannot access the event `e` parameter?

```
//keyObject is a predefined variable

<Form.Control
  type="text"
  value={this.state.productObject[keyObject].name || ""}
  placeholder={"name"}
  onChange={(e) => {
    this.setState(function (prevState) {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        productObject: {
          ...prevState.productObject,
          [keyObject]: {
            name: e.target.value,
            price: prevState.productObjecy[keyObject].price,
            selected: prevState.productObject[keyObject].selected,
          },
        },
      };
    });
  }}
/>;
```

When I attempt to change the value of the field, I get the 'Cannot read property 'value' of null' error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

`e.target.name.value`

An easy way to debug this is to do `console.log(e.target)` and see what you need next.